# Can't move div element more to the left

Tags: css

Please see this div structure:

```
<div class="columnbox" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="paging">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltPagingBottom" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And these classes:

```
.paging{width:650px;border:#000000 0px solid;height:20px;}

.columnbox{ background-color:#f6f6f6;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;width:96%;padding:10px;margin:0 10px 10px 0;line-height:17px;}
```

For some reason the paging buttons fall outside the columnbox box and I can't seem to correct it.

I tried adding properties to the .paging class:

```
margin-left:-100px; padding:0px;
```

I also tried changing the columnbox class with

```
padding:0px;
```

But that also doesn't help. What can I do?

Comment: Could you show the code of your `<div>`? Simply linking to your website will get your question closed as "Too Localized."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - Add to `.columnbox {display: inline-block; }`

The total width of the containing element is a little off after the fact, but that is an easy fix for you to play with.  You can decrease width of the next/previous buttons some, or increase width of columnbox from 96% to 98% to match.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.paging{
position: absolute
}` to the css, that way the element will position itself relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element (.columnbox). After that fiddle a bit with the columnbox height. That did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

add property `float:left` and `width:100%` to your `.columnbox` class

and add property `float:left` to `.paging` class

Answer (score 0):

add `float:left` to `.columnbox {}`